# Restrict visibility of classes by specific assembly

Tags: c#, design-patterns, visibility

I currently working on an application which includes a communication module which uses a TCP server and a TCP client. The communication module includes a directory "Core" which contains private classes to do the internal functioning of the communication module.

My goal is to create unit tests for classes in the "Core" directory. But, they are not accessible from the test project.

Is there a method, or a design pattern that could allow me to prevent the use of these classes outside the assembly, except for the test assembly?

Thank you,

Comment: The general practice is to make them internal, and then use the InternalsVisibleTo attribute on your assembly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make the internal classes available to YourTestProject by adding this line:

```
[assembly: InternalsVisibleTo("YourTestProject")]
```

in the AssemblyInfo.cs of the project you want to test.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [InternalsVisibleTo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.compilerservices.internalsvisibletoattribute.aspx) attribute, to make the internal classes visible to the test assembly.